# Vue - Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

New to Vue, very simple component and sometimes when I run `npm run serve` or simply save a file that it's already serving i'll get the following

```
E:\Development\website\app>npm run serve

> website@0.0.1 serve E:\Development\website\app
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                                                                                                                             17:08:52

 error  in ./src/components/LoginModal.vue

Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

E:\Development\website\app\src\components\LoginModal.vue
  3:13  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}"

  1 | <script>
  2 |     export default {
> 3 |         name: 'LoginModal',
    |             ^
  4 |         props: {},
  5 |         data: () => {
  6 |             return {

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& 2:0-49 7:16-26
 @ ./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.45.105:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

But there isn't an unexpected "}", the error is occasionally 
`1:1 error  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "<"`

It's driving me nuts. Any ideas?

Comment: can you share the full code?

Answer (score 0):

Error was because I created an `.eslintrc.js` file when my package.json had the linting rules in it?